# Is it true that $E[e^{tX}] \le e^{E[t^2X^2/2]}$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, probability-inequalities

I've seen some one use the inequality
$E_X[e^{tX}] \le e^{E_X[t^2X^2/2]}$.
However, I don't know if it is true and can not prove it.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It's always good to try special cases, like, say, $X = 1$ with probability one (conclusion?) or, $X \sim \mathrm{Ber}(p)$. Even more qualitatively, note that a random variable can have a second moment without its moment generating function being finite, which is already enough to disprove such a result in full generality, without even having to exhibit explicit counterexamples.

Comment: Maybe you could provide some more context on where you saw this or, perhaps, additional constraints placed on the distribution of $X$.

Comment: I think this has something to do with Jensen's inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this inequality could in practice appear in relation with the normal distribution (although this is not restrictive of course).

The **LHS** denotes the moment generating function (MGF) of a random variable, as a function of any real $t$, and the MGF of a normal $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ distribution is

$$MGF(t) = \exp\left \{\frac 12 t^2\sigma^2+t\mu \right\}$$

The **RHS** equals 
$$RHS =\exp\left \{E(t^2X^2/2)\right\}=\exp\left \{\frac {t^2}{2}E(X^2)\right\} = \exp\left \{\frac {t^2}{2}\left[\operatorname{Var}(X) + \left(E(X)\right)^2 \right]\right\}$$

and if $X$ is normal, we have

$$RHS = \exp\left \{\frac {t^2}{2}\left(\sigma^2 + \mu^2 \right)\right\}  $$

So in case of $X$ being normal the examined inequallity is written as

$$\exp\left \{\frac 12 t^2\sigma^2+t\mu \right\} \le\;?\;\exp\left \{\frac {t^2}{2}\left(\sigma^2 + \mu^2 \right)\right\}$$

and simplifying

$$\Rightarrow e^{t\mu } \le\;?\;e^{t^2\mu^2/2} \Rightarrow t\mu \le\;?\; \frac 12 t^2\mu^2$$

Now it is easy to formulate the conditions under which this inequality will or will not hold (always for the case of $X$ being a normal random variable).